# What is the canonical method to calculate the surface brightness limit of a 2D image, e.g., in a 1 arcsec2 aperture?

Tags: observational-astronomy, photometry

What is the canonical method to calculate the surface brightness limit of a 2D image, e.g., in a 1 arcsec2 aperture?
...if image has erg/s/cm2 units and each pixel has some arcsec2 dimension.

Comment: If the units are as you say then the image is already in surface brightness units. Do you mean how do you calculate the average surface brightness over a square arcsecond? How big are your pixels - presumably much smaller than 1 arcsecond? Add up the surface brightness over $n$ pixels and divide by $n$.

Comment: @RobJeffries thank you! 
I need to calculate the "surface brightness limit" (how deep the image is) in 1 square arcesec. Following what you said, shall I sum the surface brightness over a region of 1 arcsec (far from any source, so that I take only noise) and divide by the number of pixels in the region?

Other question..what about the surface brightness radial profile?
Is it the sum of pixels in any annulus divided by the area in the annulus?

Comment: I don't think you can use ergs, unless you're just asking for energy output rather than photopic brightness, or lumens, etc.